# Getting a ClassNotFoundException, when reading classes from a JarInputStream to a List

Tags: java, jar

I am reading in a Jar file, and separating the files into individual classes, using the JarInputStream. If I print out the names in the console it works fine, but when I try to use Class.forName(name) and add it to my list, the program throws a ClassNotFoundException.

```
 list = new ClassList();

    JarInputStream in = new JarInputStream(new FileInputStream(new File("test-jar.jar")));

    JarEntry next = in.getNextJarEntry();

    while (next != null) 
    {
         if (next.getName().endsWith(".class")) 
         {
             String name = next.getName().replaceAll("/", "\\.");

             name = name.replaceAll(".class", "");

             if (!name.contains("$")) name.substring(0, name.length() - ".class".length());

             System.out.println(name);

             Class queryClass;

             try {
                 queryClass = Class.forName(name);
                 list.add(queryClass);
             } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                 e.printStackTrace();
             }

             System.out.println(list.size());
         }
         next = in.getNextJarEntry();

    }
```

*The Package name:*
**ie.gmit.sw**

**Class Names**
Artisan, GalaxianPlayer, Hobbyable, Lawyer, Pasttimable, Playerable, PokerPlayer, Runner, Scientist, Worker, SnookerPlayer, StampCollector, Student

The stack trace

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: ie.gmit.sw.Playerable
ie.gmit.sw.Runner
1
ie.gmit.sw.Playerable
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
    at ie.gmit.sw.ReadinJarFile.main(ReadinJarFile.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
1
ie.gmit.sw.Scientist
1
ie.gmit.sw.PokerPlayer
1
ie.gmit.sw.SnookerPlayer
1
ie.gmit.sw.Lawyer
1
ie.gmit.sw.Worker
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147)
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: ie.gmit.sw.Scientist
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
    at ie.gmit.sw.ReadinJarFile.main(ReadinJarFile.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147)
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: ie.gmit.sw.PokerPlayer
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
    at ie.gmit.sw.ReadinJarFile.main(ReadinJarFile.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147)
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: ie.gmit.sw.SnookerPlayer
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
    at ie.gmit.sw.ReadinJarFile.main(ReadinJarFile.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147)
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: ie.gmit.sw.Lawyer
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
    at ie.gmit.sw.ReadinJarFile.main(ReadinJarFile.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147)
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: ie.gmit.sw.Worker
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
    at ie.gmit.sw.ReadinJarFile.main(ReadinJarFile.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147)
1
```

Comment: OK. And what is your question?

Comment: Why am i getting the Exception? and how do i stop it? Also it doesn't seem to be adding the classes to the list.

Comment: Knowing the content of the jar file, the name of the class you're trying to load, and most importantly, the stack trace of the exception, might help then. We can't read your screen.

Comment: Post that, and the rest of what I asked for, correctly formatted in your question. Not in comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to load any `class` from a `jar` file, that `jar` file should be present in your application `classpath`. Reading a jar file using `JarInputStream` will not add that jar in your `classpath`. Add that jar in your application `classpath` and this `exception` will disappear.

Comment: Thanks that was the answer.